# PHP Image URL from /buildimg.php?1=2816 to /picture_2816.png?

Tags: php, html, gd

How can I change the URL from a PHP extension to a PNG extension? I am making an image generator for users to post their score on a test on forums. The main targeted forum, though, does not allow php extensions in images. How can I change this URL:

```
http://everythingtutorials.org/noobtest/buildimg.php?1=2816
```

to something like this:

```
http://everythingtutorials.org/noobtest/picture_2816.png
```

Comment: It would take some implementation of mod_rewrite like `RewriteRule ([0-9]+)\.png$ /noobtest/buildimg.php?1=$1 [L]`

Comment: In your .htaccess Can't promise that is the answer though. My regex isn't that great, but the answer you are looking for is somewhere down that path.

Comment: Thanks Ill try your suggestion

Comment: @jbman223 I was about to answer with how to create a `.htaccess` file, but would you rather post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking is done at the webserver level, before the request reaches PHP. You need to configure your webserver to send all requests for the desired URL format to the PHP script.

You don't state what webserver you're using. The following answer applies if you're using Apache, which is arguably the most common webserver for powering PHP sites.

One way to do this is using the Apache [mod_rewrite module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). `mod_rewrite` allows Apache to "rewrite" specific URLs to transform them into other URLs.

The specific Apache directive you want are:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/noobtest/picture_([0-9]+)\.png$ /noobtest/buildimg.php?id=$1 [L]
```

These should be placed into your Apache's `<VirtualHost>` configuration directive in `httpd.conf` or similar. **If you don't have access to the server's configuration, you can try placing these in a `.htaccess` file**. [`.htaccess` files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) are per-directory configuration files (names, you guessed it, `.htaccess`) which contain Apache directives. Using a `.htaccess` file is less efficient but may be required.

To set up a RewiteRule using a `.htaccess` file, create a file `/noobtest/.htaccess` containing:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^picture_([0-9]+)\.png$ buildimg.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Note that you don't specify the directory here. Also, note that **mod_rewrite must be loaded by your server already** and **you must have permission (via `AllowOverride`) to override Apache's configuration in this way**. If either of those is not true and you can't modify Apache's configuration files, you're out of luck.

Comment: Don't forget the `[L]` at the end of the RewriteRule. It doesn't matter if there are no more RewriteRules, but there's no reason to get into a bad habit.

Comment: I am using an Apache Server. I think have access to my main httpd.conf file. I will try to add the firs snippet of code to it. Will I need to change any of my code for it to work?

Comment: @Grexis Thanks, it is better practice to add the Last flag. Also, I totally messed up, I tried to ask *you* if you wanted to post this as an answer in the comments above but mistakenly asked the OP as well, LOL. If you post your own answer I will delete mine.

Comment: None of the script code needs to be changed. This simply maps the url to your page. You can also stick the code between `<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>` and `</ifModule>` for good measure.

Comment: @Josh, don't worry about it. It's 6 AM and I haven't slept yet. There's no way I would have done a proper job of it.

Comment: @jbman223 No, the beauty of RewriteRules is that they're done before PHP is called upon so you don't need to change your PHP code. You will, however, need to change any links/`src` attributes of images. This makes the new formed URLs work but doesn't magically change all URLs to be this new form.

Comment: Good point about `ifModule` @Grexis although I'd argue that if the module's not available it could lead to confusing situations, i.e. *I have my RewriteRules in there, why aren't they working!?!?* Totally depends on the situation. If an invalid `httpd.conf` will bring down multiple sites, add the `<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>` directive.